# DDRescue locks system up on disk clone

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, clone, ddrescue

I have ddrescue running on the latest version of Fedora trying to clone a dying IDE disk. When I run ddrescue --no-split /dev/sdb imagefile logfile the copy will happen then the entire system will lock up.

Is this normal for a disk clone?

Comment: What sort of disk are we talking? And what does the logs say? (both dmesg and ddrescue). I've had it happen with CF cards a lot, as the buffer gets clogged. If this is your problem, patience is the key.

Comment: I have no way to view the logs unless I force a shutdown by unplugging the computer. I could do that. As far as disk goes, its an old IDE disk connected via IDE cable to a MB. the main disk is a SATA also connected to the MB where the data is being copied too. So I should wait and hope for the system to unlock? Can I increase the buffer?

Comment: The buffer is hardware, so no way to increase it. Seeing as it's IDE, I would think you're suffering from I/O clogging. Give it some time. If it doesn't help, do a hard reset and reasess. Perhaps by doing the same thing again while monitoring logs.

Comment: This is my 3rrd time trying to copy from the IDE drive to the SATA and having the entire OS/computer lock up to where the mouse does not move or anything so I doubt I'll be able to monitor the logs. Anyway to I/O limit?

Comment: Is it normal for a drive that has failed to lock up while attempting to read the bad sectors, yes, that is normal.